# How to create a table of Parent & child xml attributes in vb 2015

Tags: database, visual-studio-2015, xml-parsing

I need to create a database based on xml file attribute values so i managed to create some schemas for some tables from parent nodes, the issue i am facing with child nodes is that there are some attributes with the same name as in parent nodes  so i changed there names in the table schema but in this case i will face a problem with inserting values for from xml file.
Note: there so many attributes in each node which i can't manually write them in my code.
I am using vb 2015.
Will be very grateful for Any help